# I have time-series data for entry/exit counts for different train stations, how can I standardize the datetime frequency across the data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series, interpolation

The data that I currently have resembles something like the table below:

Station A operates from 12AM to 1AM, Station B operates from 1AM to 2AM and Station C operates from 2AM onwards.

| Date Time | Station | Entries | Exits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |

I would like to add in additional rows so that my dataframe holds 'n' rows at each unique hour frequency, where n is the number of unique Stations. In this example it would mean 3 rows (for Stations A, B, C) for 12AM, 1AM and 2AM for a total of 9. What  pandas functions can I use to convert the above table to a format similar to the one below?

| Date Time | Station | Entries | Exits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station B | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | Station C | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station A | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | Station C | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | Station A | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | Station B | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 02:00:00 | Station C | 3 | 3 |

Also including code for generating the initial dataframe below for ease of reference.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date Time':pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00', 
                                                '2023-01-01 01:00:00',  '2023-01-01 02:00:00', 
                                                '2023-01-01 02:00:00']),
     'Station':['Station A', 'Station A', 'Station B', 'Station B', 'Station C'],
     'Entries':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
     'Exits':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]}
)
```

I've tried using groupby and resampling with hourly frequency, but although this fills in the gaps for hours in between, it does not backfill (i.e. adding additional rows for Station C for the hours of 12 and 1 AM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first perform a long-to-wide conversion using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), you can then use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) with `dropna=False` to create the additional rows:

```
(df
 .pivot(index='Date Time', columns='Station')
 .stack(dropna=False)
 .fillna(0)
 .astype('int')
 .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date Time': ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 02:00:00', '2023-01-01 02:00:00'],
                   'Station': ['Station A', 'Station A', 'Station B', 'Station B', 'Station C'],
                   'Entries': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                   'Exits': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]})

df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
df.set_index('Date Time', inplace=True)
df_pivoted = df.groupby('Station').resample('H').sum().reset_index().pivot_table(index='Date Time', columns='Station', values=['Entries', 'Exits'], fill_value=0)
df_pivoted.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df_pivoted.columns.values]
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.reset_index().fillna(0)
df_unpivoted = df_pivoted.melt(id_vars=['Date Time'], var_name='Type_Station', value_name='Count')
df_unpivoted[['Type', 'Station']] = df_unpivoted['Type_Station'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df_unpivoted.drop('Type_Station', axis=1)
grouped = df.groupby(['Date Time', 'Station','Type']).sum()
print(grouped)
```

This should be close to what you want, please continue to modify to get your result by duplicate and row to column

[image]